# Dealing with out of range value on varchar date conversion

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, types, date-conversion

I'm attempting to convert dates input in our system as text in the format `YYYYMMDD` into dates. Unfortunately our system allows the use of the 31st of any month to signify that it's the last day of the month that's important, for some functions like interest accrual etc.

I have a date showing as `20160931` which obviously fails to convert via

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), [FIELD]))
```

and throws the out-of-range value error.

How can I overcome this, so that I can convert it to the correct value, in this case `30/09/2016`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```
DECLARE @YourDate VARCHAR(100)='20160231';

SELECT CAST(y+m+dNew AS DATE)
FROM (VALUES(LEFT(@YourDate,4)
           ,SUBSTRING(@YourDate,5,2)
           ,SUBSTRING(@YourDate,7,2))) AS Parts(y,m,d)
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN CAST(m AS INT) IN(4,6,9,11) AND CAST(d AS INT)>30 THEN '30' 
           ELSE CASE WHEN CAST(m AS INT)=2 AND CAST(d AS INT)>28 THEN '28' ELSE d END 
           END AS dNew
) AS NewDay
```

And about a 29th of February you just have - additionally - to check if the year is to be divided by 4 :-)

### UPDATE

Now it's on me to evolve @Irawan's technique :-)

Since SQL Server 2005 has not got the `EOMONTH` function, but it is surely better to let SQL Server do the calculation (29th of Feb implicitly solved!), I'd suggest this:

```
DECLARE @YourDate VARCHAR(100)='20160231';

SELECT DATEADD(SECOND,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,1,CAST(y+m+'01' AS DATETIME)))
FROM (VALUES(LEFT(@YourDate,4)
           ,SUBSTRING(@YourDate,5,2)
           ,SUBSTRING(@YourDate,7,2))) AS Parts(y,m,d)
```

This will - in any case - deliver the last second of the month...

If you want a plain `DATE` (without a time), you might just change the `SECOND` to `DAY` which will first jump to midnight of the first day of the **next** month and than go one day back...

### UPDATE 2 Use existing dates if valid

Simple syntax...

```
DECLARE @YourDate VARCHAR(100)='20160229';

SELECT CASE WHEN ISDATE(@YourDate)=1 THEN @YourDate 
            ELSE DATEADD(SECOND,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,1,CAST(LEFT(@YourDate,4) + SUBSTRING(@YourDate,5,2) +'01' AS DATETIME)))
            END AS CorrectDate;
```

Comment: Apologies, I should have been clearer in my original question. Within the field, I have real valid dates as well which I don't want to move/change.

Comment: @GavinP Please see my Update 2

Answer (score 2):

Adapting @Shnugo's technic, I feel it's better to leave SQL to decide the end of month. Hence:

```
SELECT eomonth(CAST(y+m+'01' AS DATE))
FROM (VALUES(LEFT(@YourDate,4)
           ,SUBSTRING(@YourDate,5,2)
           ,SUBSTRING(@YourDate,7,2))) AS Parts(y,m,d)
```

Will give '2016-02-29' instead of '2016-02-28' with a constant '28' for Feb.

Comment: The `EOMONTH` function is not available in 2005. Might read the update in my answer... (+1 from my side anyway)